# Какие отличия объектно- ориентированного от прототипного программирования?

Tags: ооп

Какие значительные и не очень отличия между этими подходами?

Comment: Прототипное – одна из реализаций ООП, в этом ключе отличий нет. Совсем.

Comment: @D-side, вероятно речь про `class-based` vs `prototype-based`

Comment: [Class-based vs prototype-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Class-based_vs_prototype-based)

Comment: @Grundy наверняка.